# How can I get acknowledgment at client side without closing server socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, servlets, network-programming

I'm able to send string to the server and server also received the same. Server is able to send the acknowledgment but client is not getting acknowledged until server ends the connection. But I don't want to close the connection. How should I display the acknowledgment without closing the connection?

```
//This is Client    
public void Actuator1_Stop(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1028);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dout.writeUTF("Stop_Actuator");
        dout.flush();
        System.out.println("Command Sent = Stop_Actuator");

        //Get the return message from server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("ACK received from the server : " +message);
        socket.close();
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//This is Server
class Socket4 implements Runnable  {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1028);
            while(true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                String cmd = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Command= "+cmd);

                //Sending the response back to the client
                String ack = null;
                OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                if(cmd.equals("Stop_Actuator")) {
                        ack= "Ok";
                        bw.write(ack);
                   } else {
                        ack = "Error";
                        bw.write(ack);
                   }

                   System.out.println("ACK sent to the client is "+ack);
                   bw.flush();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket1 s1 = new Socket1();
        Socket2 s2 = new Socket2();
        Socket3 s3 = new Socket3();
        Socket4 s4 = new Socket4();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(s1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(s2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(s3);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(s4);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();   
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: 'ack= "Ok";' - does that look line a line of text that readline() would return?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I'm getting the ack at client side.

Comment: Why are you sending lines in one direction and using `writeUTF()` in the other direction? Be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I display the acknowledgment without closing the connection?

In your client you are doing a read-line:

```
String message = br.readLine();
```

However from the server you are not sending a complete line.  You need to add line termination characters to the end of the message:

```
ack = "Ok\n";
bw.write(ack);
```

The read-line then completes and the client gets the ack.  Obviously the error ack also needs a newline (`"Error\n"`).

Make sure that you are properly closing the accepted socket and the server socket that are created in `Socket4.run()`.  I assume that you are just posting portions of your code but make sure to close those sockets in a try/finally blocks.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I'm getting the ack at client side.